# How to define array from another defined array?

Tags: arrays, cplex

I have this array [1,3,2,5] and i want to generate this one [1,3,3,3,2,2,5,5,5,5,5] from the first array how to do this in cplex ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would use scripting

```
int n=4;
range r=1..n;

int a[r]=[1,3,2,5];

tuple t
{
  key int rank;
  int value;
}

{t} s={};

execute
{
  var rank=0;
  for(var i in r)
  {
    for(var j=1;j<=a[i];j++)
    {
      rank++;
      s.add(rank,a[i])
    }
  }
}

int b[k in 1..card(s)]=item(s,<k>).value;
execute
{
  writeln(b);
}
```

gives

```
[1 3 3 3 2 2 5 5 5 5 5]
```

Comment: Dear Dr. Alex firstly i'd like to thank you, another concern a[] is a decision variable array that its values are generated in the constrains, b[] is generated from a[]. So i can only write your above code after my constrains and the issue is that, i want to use b[] in another decision constrains. when i tried this gives me error because b[] is not defined yet it's defined after the constrains and i want to use it in another array in the constrains. How to solve this??

Comment: If your array b is used in a second model you can write b in a file and use it as input for second model or use flow control (main block) to do that

Comment: thank you dr alex for your effort with me, another question if you don't mind " i have a decision variable array c[n] where n equal the same range/size of s{} and i want every value in this decision variable to be less than these value in s{}                                                                   i wrote::
forall(k in 1..card(s))
c [k]  <= item(s,<k>).value;                                                                                       there are no errors but the values of c[n] are not forced to be less than the values of s{}                     c[1]<= 1 and c[2]<=3 ..

Comment: Do not hesitate to Start a New question in stackoverflow